# React Native - UseEffect Constantly Updates

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I am using useEffect to get the total jigsaw pieces from my async storage to be displayed on the home page. I use async storage to get the number of jigsaws stored in the storage then for each jigsaw, i add the total amount of jigsaw pieces. I do this within useEffect as the total amount of jigsaw pieces may change depending on if the user adds more jigsaw to their collection. However, when i use useEffect, my total amount of jigsaw pieces constantly updates and never stops.

Code:

```
let [totalPieces, setTotalPieces] = useState(0);
  const [numJigsaw, setNumJigsaw] = useState([]);
  const getNumOfJigsaw = async () => {
    try {
      setNumJigsaw(await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys());
    } catch (e) {}
    return numJigsaw;
  };
  const getAllJigsaw = async () => {
    let jigsaws = await getNumOfJigsaw();
    for (let z = 0; z < jigsaws.length; z++) {
      let currentJigsaw = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem(jigsaws[z]));
      setTotalPieces(totalPieces+ parseFloat(currentJigsaw.pieces));
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllJigsaw();
  }, [totalPieces]);
```

I believe the issue is because totalPieces is dependant? Im not entirely sure though.

Comment: The array you're passing into `useEffect` - `[totalPieces]` - tells that function to update whenever any item in `totalPieces` changes.

Comment: How would i change it so that it only updates once every time the page is loaded?

Comment: I think your useEffect should be looking at `numJigsaw`, not `totalPieces`. In your `try`, you're fetching all the keys - so do the count there. You should only need to update the effect if that endpoint gets more pieces (I think).

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by do the count in the try statement. Also changing the dependency to numJigsaw does not fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you've set the effect to run when `totalPieces` changes (via the dependency).

The effect (when the async stuff resolves) sets `totalPieces`, so the effect is run again due to that dependency, etc, etc.

It sounds like you're looking for something like

```
const [totalPieces, setTotalPieces] = useState(0);
const [jigsawKeys, setJigsawKeys] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const jigsaws = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
    let total = 0;
    for (let z = 0; z < jigsaws.length; z++) {
      let currentJigsaw = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem(jigsaws[z]));
      total += parseFloat(currentJigsaw.pieces);
    }
    setJigsawKeys(jigsaws);
    setTotalPieces(total);
  })();
}, [totalPieces]);
```

all in all (I renamed `numJigsaw` to `jigsawKeys` so it makes more sense).

Comment: How would i resolve this issue? I need it to update whenever i load the page

Comment: Change the dependency array to `[]` – that will have the effect run only on mount.

Comment: @WIK28 Please see my edit. :)

Comment: This code works however, is there a way for it to update when i revisit the page again? If i add a new jigsaw to my collection, it should update the total pieces when i revisit the page again. Or is there a way to refresh the page every time i visit?

Comment: The effect will rerun when the component is mounted again. Are you sure the storage state is changing?

Comment: Yes, i have checked that the puzzle was added to my collection and the total pieces has not been updated.

Comment: If it helps, the local storage is changing on a different page which is why i mentioned about refreshing the page every time i revisit